# Column names conflict in a MySQL join

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables called kingdom and player.

**kingdom table:**

```
+----------------------------------------
| ID | kingdom              | timestamp |
+----------------------------------------
| 1  | Kingdom 47           | time      |
| 2  | Kingdom 48           | time      |
----------------------------------------+
```

**player table:**

```
+---------------------------------------+
| ID | name                 | kingdom   |
+---------------------------------------+
| 7  | some name            | 1         |
| 8  | some name            | 1         |
| 9  | some name            | 1         |
+---------------------------------------+
```

I would like to join them and get out some thing like the one below:

I want the output like this:

```
+-----------------------------------------+
| ID | name                 | kingdom     |
+-----------------------------------------+
| 7  | some name            | Kingdom 47  |
| 8  | some name            | Kingdom 47  |
| 9  | some name            | Kingdom 47  |
+-----------------------------------------+
```

I tried this:

```
 SELECT p.id, p.name, p.kingdom
 FROM player p, kingdom k
 WHERE k.id=p.kingdom and kingdom LIKE "%K47%";
```

I'm using MySQL 5.7.

Comment: which dbms you are using mysql or mariadb?

Comment: I'm using MYSQL Server 5.7

Comment: By the time it took to write this question you could have read a tutorial to solve this problem.

Comment: What query do you currently use?

Comment: I'm new to MYSQL, tried alot of things but no luck. I've been googling for almost 4 hours now with no luck whatsoever.

Comment: Pro-tips for posting (and to help you avoid downvotes): don't shout in all-caps. There's no need to add "help required", "please help" or any other material that will be construed as begging. Always add your attempt - I have added that to your post, but it is still missing a description of what output that gave you. Always show your research, if only to show you're not looking for free work. Readers don't want to know how long you've been stuck, that's just more pleading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT P.ID , P.name, K.kingdom
FROM player p 
INNER JOIN kingdom K ON K.ID = p.kingdom
```

Comment: **THANKS IT WORKED** You are a life savor.